# access content of ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template

is there a way how to access the raw content of a ng-template element. I would need this for a special use case where I need to print the contents of the template as string onto a page for documentation purposes.

Angular processes all ng-templates and renders placeholder comments in the DOM.

```
<ng-template>FOO</ng-template>
```

I need to gain access to the "FOO" string

Comment: you can use `ElementRef` to achieve this

Comment: no, not really. since the ng-template ends up being an empty comment in DOM , e.g. <!-- -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not to handle it from typescript. 
you can use Angular 2 - innerHTML styling in which you can access this varibale throught the component and can print it anywhere you want.

just assign your "Foo" to innerHTML variable and you can use this variable for further use. for more see [this](https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/)

Comment: This could actually work. I'll give it a try. Thanks.