# Get the contents of ng-template as a string before it's compiled by Angular

Tags: angular

I need to get the contents of a `ng-template` as a string, **before it's compiled by Angular**. The reason for this is that I need to display this as a string next to the compiled template, so you can see what the code behind the rendered component looks like.

So for this template:

```
<ng-template #exampleRef>
  <lib-input [formControl]="ctrl" label="Default" placeholder="Default"></lib-input>
</ng-template>
```

I would expect this result (when doing a `console.log` for example):

```
<lib-input [formControl]="ctrl" label="Default" placeholder="Default"></lib-input>
```

Been looking at `ViewContainerRef` and `TemplateRef` mostly but can't find what I'm looking for. Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663519/access-content-of-ng-template) which asks the same thing but lacks a clear answer.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first time ? (I'm asking because I highly doubt this is doable, the templates are compiled AOT).

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I know it's a stretch, but I'm forced to write a Storybook-like application where I can show examples of component uses and the code was used to render it. I would use Storybook but it's absolutely terrible for Angular...